# Problems with if/else statements nested in a while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

The program is a standard flight database using OOP. In this main method there are 5 options that execute different tasks. Options 1 and 2 work without a problem, but for some reason options 3-5 don't execute. The code inside the if/else if's of options 3-5 do not run, and the program just outputs the main menu again.

```
boolean exit = false;
while (exit == false)
{
  System.out.println("Now what would you like to do?");
  System.out.println("1. Print out a flight's info");
  System.out.println("2. Print out the number of flights through the static variable");
  System.out.println("3. Change the departure time of a flight");
  System.out.println("4. Change the departure gate of a flight");
  System.out.println("5. Exit");

  int choice = sc.nextInt();

  if (choice == 1)
  {
    System.out.println("Which flight would you like to print (1 or 2)?");
    int choice2 = sc.nextInt();
    if (choice2 == 1)
    {
      f1.printFlight();
    }
    else if (choice2 == 2)
    {
      f2.printFlight();
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Invalid choice");
    }
  }

  else if (choice == 2)
  {
    System.out.println("This is the number of flights: ");
    int numFlights = f1.getNumFlights();
    System.out.println(numFlights);
  }

  else if (choice == 3)
  {
    System.out.println("Which flight would you like to change the departure time of (1 or 2)?");
    int choice3 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(choice3);

    if (choice3 == 1)
    {
      System.out.println("What is the new departure time for flight " + choice3);
      int newTime = sc.nextInt();
      f1.changeDeptTime(newTime);
    }

    else if (choice3 == 2)
    {
      f2.changeDeptTime();
    }

    else
    {
      System.out.println("Invalid choice");
    }
  }

  else if (choice == 4)
  {
    System.out.println("Which flight would you like to change the departure gate of (1 or 2)?");
    int choice4 = sc.nextInt();

    if (choice4 == 1)
    {
      f1.changeDeptGate();
    }

    else if (choice4 == 2)
    {
      f2.changeDeptGate();
    }

    else
    {
      System.out.println("Invalid choice");
    }
  }

  else if (choice == 5)
  {
    System.out.println("Exit Reached");
    exit = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: could you attach the output block?

Comment: Is there a particular sequence you're entering the input choices?  If you do 1 and or 2 before 3, 4. or 5, or if you enter 3, 4, or 5 first, does the problem still happen in both situations?

Comment: Which flight would you like to print (1 or 2)?
1
Flight name: A
Destination: New York
Departure time: A1
Departure gate: 11:00 AM
Now what would you like to do?
1. Print out a flight's info
2. Print out the number of flights through the static variable
3. Change the departure time of a flight
4. Change the departure gate of a flight
5. Exit
3
Which flight would you like to change the departure time of (1 or 2)?
Now what would you like to do?
1. Print out a flight's info
2. Print out the number of flights through the static variable
3. Change the departure time of a flight etc..
@ADi

Comment: The problem still happens regardless of the order. I think it has something to do with scanners of options 3, 4, and 5 maybe? @DBug

Comment: I cut/pasted this into a small test program, and all 5 choices worked correctly.  You may have to show entire program (if not too large).

Answer (score 0):

Use switch() statement for the choices for each case. Like

```
switch(x) {
    case 1:
        doSomething1();
    case 2:
        doSomething2();
    case 3:
        doSomething3();
}
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.